# Dynamics Workflow Action: Entity Reference Arguments not showing in Assign Value step

Tags: process, dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-365

I am trying to create an action that retrieves the Lookup (*EntityReference*) for a given Input value. The Action calls upon a custom Code Activity as the first Step which is working properly (at least from the trace log I am generating). Two main issues I have with this:

1. Process Arguments of type *EntityReference* do not show in the Assign Value Details list
2. *EntityReference* outputs from the Code Activity are not showing up in the list of available fields from the first Action Step.

Perhaps the two issues are related but all the documentation/examples I have read do not include EntityReferences as outputs so I wonder if I am missing something or there is a bug in the system.

Anyway, if someone is interested, I am defining the Outputs in the Code Activity as follows.

```cs
[Input("Project Code")]
public InArgument<string> ProjectCode { get; set; }
        
[Output("Project LookupRef")]
[ReferenceTarget("tbl_projectcode")]
public OutArgument<EntityReference> ProjectCodeRef { get; set; }
```

The Code Activity takes the input and searches the table with that code and returns the record found as an *EntityReference*. The trace log shows the inputs and outputs are read and generated correctly so I am confident that the code is good. But the interface with the CRM screens is not working as expected.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `EntityReference` can perfectly be used as an output parameter. It will only show up when you have your cursor in a lookup field of the proper entity type. Attribute `ReferenceTarget` must define the entity logical name for the `EntityReference`. Did you use the proper name? What do you mean with "Assign Value Details list"? Could you share a screen shot?

Comment: Thanks @HenkvanBoeijen! While trying to take a few screenshots to answer your comment, I discovered that there was an Entity dropdown when defining the Arguments of _EntityReference_ type which I had not seen before. Once I selected the reference, those output arguments started to show in the "Assign Value Details" list. BTW, the "details" list is displayed when adding an "Assign Value" step to the Process/Action.  Thanks again for making me go over it again. :)